# Obviously incorrect C++ code was accepted by cl.exe compiler

Tags: c++, cl

I wonder why the following C++ code is accepted by Microsoft cl.exe compiler from Visual Studio 2012?

```
int x;
struct A {}
decltype(x) y;
```

It looks like an obvious mistake, but the code above is compilable. Note, however, that the following code is correctly rejected:

```
int x;
struct A {}
int y;
```

Comment: Does that version of Visual C++ support `decltype` as a keyword at all?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, it does.

Comment: Not sure what you want any of us to say here. Raise a bug on Microsoft Connect and move on...

Comment: I wonder that for many other lines of code too, they seem to call it "feature" or "extension", I would call it bug.

Comment: The debugger shows that `y`'s type is `int`. Probably a bug. Interestingly, the intellisense parser rejects the code (underlines it in red and hints "did you forget a ';'?") even though the compiler doesn't.

Comment: It's clearly wrong. So I guess you need to submit a bug report. I don't think that SO is the place to do that.

Comment: They've fixed it in VS2013.

Comment: @40two: Then there's not much point in filing a bug.

Comment: @bronikkk - Do you try to fool people that don't run VC++?

Comment: This is probably going to get closed as "unclear what you're asking".  In particular, it's unclear whether you are asking whether the behavior is intentional, or assuming it is intentional and asking for a rationale.

Comment: @BenVoigt I guess there's not.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Not true. If MS weren't aware of this issue _specifically_ but it happened to be fixed by some other change, reporting this will enable them to add a regression test for it and prevent it from being re-introduced at a later date.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit as I've already said the joy of helping proprietary software becomming better is priceless.

Comment: What do you mean it's an obvious mistake? What's wrong with the code?

Comment: @0x499602D2: What did you expect `struct A {} decltype(x) y;` to do?

Comment: @0x499602D2 missing a semicolon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is a bug. Raise it on Microsoft Connect and move on to something else!